# Change azure storage setting for Microsoft Bot service

Tags: azure, settings, azure-storage, botframework, bots

Previously I have create a new web app bot. However, I have chosen the wrong settle for azure storage. Could someone advise me on changing Azure storage to another storage account?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the App settings in Application Settings. 
Change the connection string of what you want to `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboar`.

[image]

Then, click the All App service settings in web app bot. And click Application Settings in App Service, it will change automatically.

[image]